# how do I clear last query from cache

Tags: python, json, bottle

I have a python script running on bottle and it returns json data when called. Problem is that if I call the URL on the browser and keep refreshing (hitting F5), the result seems to be adding up instead of getting fresh data from the database with each refresh. E.g. if I get 1 result on query one, then I refresh the browser, I'll get 2 results instead of 1 result. The first result of the second refesh will be the data from the initial query meaning the "script/browser" hasn't forgotten the initial query.

The only way it fetches new data is when I stop and start the script via `$python3.2 myscript.py`

Is there a way to make fetching of fresh data the default behaviour whereby it won't cache the last result?

Here is my script:

```
@route('/get_member', method = "GET")
def get_member():
    key = request.query.key
    search = request.query.search
    if search == None:
        return "blank search parameter"
    elif search == "":
        return "blank search parameter"
    elif len(str(search)) < 2:
        return "search variable too short"
    hmn = None
    result = []
    params ={}
    try:
        if key == 'id':
            if valid_integer(search) == False:
                return "search should be numbers only"
            mbr = Member()
            hmn = mbr.get_id(search)
        else:
            return "wrong key provided"
        if hmn != None:
            result.append(hmn)
        hmn = None
        #save query to file
        file_name = get_day()
        f = open(file_name + ".log", "a")
        print ("Name of the file: ", f.name)
        f.write(get_time_now() + str(result) + "\n")

        #Return jason file
        from json import dumps
        response.content_type = 'application/json'
        return dumps(result)
        result = None    
    except:
        return "oops, an error occured"
    finally:
        result = None
```

Comment: The code checks whether `key` equals the string "id", and, if so, then tries to ensure that it's also a valid int.  But we already know it's "id", so how would it ever _also_ be a valid int string?  (Did this code, as it's posted, ever work?)

Comment: Also, `if valid_integer(key) != False` is better written `if valid_integer(key)`, but better yet just convert to int when you read the param: `key = int(request.query.key)` and catch a ValueError.  (Unless your app uses its own esoteric definition of "valid integer.")

Comment: Finally, to address your actual question, :) there is no Bottle cache at work here.  In fact your code snippet seems to work as you're expecting, not as you're observing, so I have to ask: is this the _actual_ code that you're running and seeing the problem with?

Comment: @ron.rothman I've corrected the key and valid query in my code and reposted. Yes, this is the code am using. As seen am trying to reset most properties to None `e.g. hmn = None and result = None` after am done with them but I still get the "cache" Am a total newbie to web apps and web services so am thinking something to do with browser cache?

Comment: @ron.rothman I've tried querying directly using console and not a browser and the same thing happens so its definitely not a browser cache thing as I was thinking a few minutes ago.....

Comment: Here's why I'm skeptical: you said that this is the code you're using, and that you're getting back an increasing list of results with each call. But, unless I'm mistaken, the bug you just fixed would prevent any results from being returned, ever. At best it would return `"search should be numbers only."` I want to help but I need to see exactly what you're executing.